# Parsing xml in C# with attribute name

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml which i get in response but sometimes some attributes are not coming so I am facing exception while parsing as I am using childnode I don't know how to parse using attribute can anyone help.

xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"><aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"><aws:OperationRequest><aws:RequestId>2f63dc1c-3ce8-c3fa-0394-e9c1c31c4246</aws:RequestId></aws:OperationRequest><aws:UrlInfoResult>
    <aws:Alexa>
      <aws:ContactInfo>
        <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
        <aws:PhoneNumbers>
          <aws:PhoneNumber/>
        </aws:PhoneNumbers>
        <aws:OwnerName/>
        <aws:Email/>
        <aws:PhysicalAddress/>
        <aws:CompanyStockTicker/>
      </aws:ContactInfo>
      <aws:ContentData>
        <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
        <aws:SiteData>
          <aws:Title>Bose</aws:Title>
          <aws:Description>Manufacturers of complete home audio systems such as home theater systems, DVD systems and accessories.</aws:Description>
        </aws:SiteData>
        <aws:LinksInCount>2368</aws:LinksInCount>
        <aws:Keywords>
          <aws:Keyword>Consumer Electronics</aws:Keyword>
        </aws:Keywords>
      </aws:ContentData>
      <aws:Related>
        <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
        <aws:Categories>
          <aws:CategoryData>
            <aws:Title>Electronics/Audio</aws:Title>
            <aws:AbsolutePath>Top/Business/Consumer_Goods_and_Services/Electronics/Audio</aws:AbsolutePath>
          </aws:CategoryData>
          <aws:CategoryData>
            <aws:Title>Shopping/Consumer Electronics</aws:Title>
            <aws:AbsolutePath>Top/Shopping/Consumer_Electronics/B</aws:AbsolutePath>
          </aws:CategoryData>
          <aws:CategoryData>
            <aws:Title>Business and Economy/Entertainment and Media</aws:Title>
            <aws:AbsolutePath>Top/Regional/North_America/United_States/Massachusetts/Localities/F/Framingham/Business_and_Economy/Entertainment_and_Media</aws:AbsolutePath>
          </aws:CategoryData>
        </aws:Categories>
      </aws:Related>
      <aws:TrafficData>
        <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
        <aws:Rank>11305</aws:Rank>
        <aws:UsageStatistics>
          <aws:UsageStatistic>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>3</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Rank>
              <aws:Value>11305</aws:Value>
              <aws:Delta>+1450</aws:Delta>
            </aws:Rank>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Rank>
                <aws:Value>11392</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>+1594</aws:Delta>
              </aws:Rank>
              <aws:PerMillion>
                <aws:Value>87.6</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-13.94%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerMillion>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:PerMillion>
                <aws:Value>5.9</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-11.85%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerMillion>
              <aws:Rank>
                <aws:Value>13240</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>1318</aws:Delta>
              </aws:Rank>
              <aws:PerUser>
                <aws:Value>2.87</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>+3%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:UsageStatistic>
          <aws:UsageStatistic>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Rank>
              <aws:Value>11396</aws:Value>
              <aws:Delta>+175</aws:Delta>
            </aws:Rank>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Rank>
                <aws:Value>11602</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>+176</aws:Delta>
              </aws:Rank>
              <aws:PerMillion>
                <aws:Value>86.9</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-0.510%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerMillion>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:PerMillion>
                <aws:Value>5.93</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-1.76%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerMillion>
              <aws:Rank>
                <aws:Value>13221</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>331</aws:Delta>
              </aws:Rank>
              <aws:PerUser>
                <aws:Value>2.92</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-1.02%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:UsageStatistic>
          <aws:UsageStatistic>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Days>7</aws:Days>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Rank>
              <aws:Value>11570</aws:Value>
              <aws:Delta>+394</aws:Delta>
            </aws:Rank>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Rank>
                <aws:Value>11949</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>+569</aws:Delta>
              </aws:Rank>
              <aws:PerMillion>
                <aws:Value>84</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-5.640%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerMillion>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:PerMillion>
                <aws:Value>5.99</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-0.41%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerMillion>
              <aws:Rank>
                <aws:Value>12951</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-102</aws:Delta>
              </aws:Rank>
              <aws:PerUser>
                <aws:Value>3.0</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>+6%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:UsageStatistic>
          <aws:UsageStatistic>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Days>1</aws:Days>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Rank>
              <aws:Value>11837</aws:Value>
              <aws:Delta>-215</aws:Delta>
            </aws:Rank>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Rank>
                <aws:Value>12937</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-21</aws:Delta>
              </aws:Rank>
              <aws:PerMillion>
                <aws:Value>78</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-0.40%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerMillion>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:PerMillion>
                <aws:Value>6.7</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>+7%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerMillion>
              <aws:Rank>
                <aws:Value>11807</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>-897</aws:Delta>
              </aws:Rank>
              <aws:PerUser>
                <aws:Value>3.8</aws:Value>
                <aws:Delta>+7%</aws:Delta>
              </aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:UsageStatistic>
        </aws:UsageStatistics>
        <aws:ContributingSubdomains>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>79.41%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>74.98%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>2.75</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>community.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>12.41%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>9.10%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>2.1</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>global.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>6.49%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>3.08%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1.4</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>pro.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>2.32%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>2.43%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>3.0</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>assets.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>4.01%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>1.89%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1.4</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>btu.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>4.24%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>1.75%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1.2</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>accommodations.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.37%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.93%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>7.3</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>downloads.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>2.54%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.90%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1.0</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>knowledgebase.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.24%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.74%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>9.1</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>gd.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.29%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.66%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>6.6</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>em.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.69%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.61%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>2.6</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>globalpressroom.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.50%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.58%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>3.3</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>hearphones.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.95%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.42%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1.3</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>reseller.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.21%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.39%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>5</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>itsm.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.17%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.25%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>4</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>auth.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.36%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.21%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1.7</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>build.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.40%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.17%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1.2</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>products.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.43%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.17%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1.1</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>employeepurchase.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.07%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.16%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>7</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>professional.bose.com</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0.23%</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.10%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>1</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
          <aws:ContributingSubdomain>
            <aws:DataUrl>OTHER</aws:DataUrl>
            <aws:TimeRange>
              <aws:Months>1</aws:Months>
            </aws:TimeRange>
            <aws:Reach>
              <aws:Percentage>0</aws:Percentage>
            </aws:Reach>
            <aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Percentage>0.49%</aws:Percentage>
              <aws:PerUser>0</aws:PerUser>
            </aws:PageViews>
          </aws:ContributingSubdomain>
        </aws:ContributingSubdomains>
      </aws:TrafficData>
    </aws:Alexa></aws:UrlInfoResult><aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"><aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode></aws:ResponseStatus>
    </aws:Response></aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

Comment: It would be a good practice to use serialization for this. Serialize your xml to an object and then read the properties.
Try starting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: hi have you seen the xml? it is quite complex to declare a class and deserialize it. Can you plz help. @Den

Comment: I always use tools to convert xml or json to C#. For XML I use http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/, just paste in your xml output and the classes will be rendered for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Response response = new Response(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Response
    {
        public Response(string filename)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

            XElement response = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Response").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace awsNs = response.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("aws");

            requestId = (string)response.Descendants(awsNs + "RequestId").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement alexa = response.Descendants(awsNs + "Alexa").FirstOrDefault();

            contentData = alexa.Elements(awsNs + "ContentData").Select(x => new ContentData() {
                urlType = (string)x.Element(awsNs + "DataUrl").Attribute("type"),
                url = (string)x.Element(awsNs + "DataUrl"),
                title = (string)x.Descendants(awsNs + "Title").FirstOrDefault(),
                description = (string)x.Descendants(awsNs + "Description").FirstOrDefault(),
                linkCount = (int)x.Element(awsNs + "LinksInCount"),
                keyWords  = x.Elements(awsNs + "Keywords").Select(y => (string)y).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();

            categoryData = alexa.Element(awsNs + "Related").Descendants(awsNs + "CategoryData")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element(awsNs + "Title"), y => (string)y.Element(awsNs + "AbsolutePath"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            trafficData = alexa.Elements(awsNs + "TrafficData").Select(x => new TrafficData() {
                rank = (int)x.Element(awsNs + "Rank"),
                statics = x.Descendants(awsNs + "UsageStatistic").Select(y => new Statistics() {
                    months = (int?)y.Descendants(awsNs + "Months").FirstOrDefault(),
                    days = (int?)y.Descendants(awsNs + "Days").FirstOrDefault(),
                    rankValue = (int)y.Element(awsNs + "Rank").Element(awsNs + "Value"),
                    rankDelta = (int)y.Element(awsNs + "Rank").Element(awsNs + "Delta"),
                    reachrankValue  = (int)y.Element(awsNs + "Reach").Element(awsNs + "Rank").Element(awsNs + "Value"),
                    reachRankDelta = (int)y.Element(awsNs + "Reach").Element(awsNs + "Rank").Element(awsNs + "Value"),
                    reachPerMillionValue = (decimal)y.Element(awsNs + "Reach").Element(awsNs + "PerMillion").Element(awsNs + "Value"),
                    reachPerMillionDeltaPercentage = decimal.Parse(((string)(y.Element(awsNs + "Reach").Element(awsNs + "PerMillion").Element(awsNs + "Delta"))).Split(new char[] {'%'}).FirstOrDefault()),
                    pageViewsPerMillionValue = (decimal)y.Element(awsNs + "PageViews").Element(awsNs + "PerMillion").Element(awsNs + "Value"),
                    pageViewsPerMillionDeltaPercentage  = decimal.Parse(((string)(y.Element(awsNs + "PageViews").Element(awsNs + "PerMillion").Element(awsNs + "Delta"))).Split(new char[] {'%'}).FirstOrDefault()),
                    pageViewsRankValue   = (int)y.Element(awsNs + "PageViews").Element(awsNs + "Rank").Element(awsNs + "Value"),
                    pageViewsRankDelta  = (int)y.Element(awsNs + "PageViews").Element(awsNs + "Rank").Element(awsNs + "Value"),
                    pageViewsPerUserValue  = (decimal)y.Element(awsNs + "PageViews").Element(awsNs + "PerUser").Element(awsNs + "Value"),
                    pageViewsPerUserDeltaPercentage  = decimal.Parse(((string)(y.Element(awsNs + "PageViews").Element(awsNs + "PerUser").Element(awsNs + "Delta"))).Split(new char[] {'%'}).FirstOrDefault())
                }).ToList(),
                contributingSubdomain = x.Descendants(awsNs + "ContributingSubdomain").Select(y => new ContributingSubdomain() {
                    dataUrl = (string)y.Element(awsNs + "DataUrl"),
                    months = (int?)y.Descendants(awsNs + "Months").FirstOrDefault(),
                    days = (int?)y.Descendants(awsNs + "Days").FirstOrDefault(),
                    reachPercentage = decimal.Parse(((string)(y.Element(awsNs + "Reach").Element(awsNs + "Percentage"))).Split(new char[] { '%' }).FirstOrDefault()),
                    pageViewsPercentage = decimal.Parse(((string)(y.Element(awsNs + "PageViews").Element(awsNs + "Percentage"))).Split(new char[] { '%' }).FirstOrDefault()),
                    pageViewsPerUser =  (decimal)y.Element(awsNs + "PageViews").Element(awsNs + "PerUser")
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();



        }

        public string requestId { get; set; }
        public ContentData contentData { get; set;}
        public Dictionary<string, string> categoryData { get; set; }
        public TrafficData trafficData { get; set; }
    }
    public class ContentData
    {
        public string urlType {get;set;}
        public string url { get; set;}
        public string title { get; set;}
        public string description { get; set;}
        public int linkCount { get;set;}
        public List<string> keyWords { get; set;}

    }
    public class TrafficData
    {
        public int rank { get;set;}
        public List<Statistics> statics { get; set;}
        public List<ContributingSubdomain> contributingSubdomain { get; set; }
    }
    public class Statistics
    {
        public int? days { get; set; }
        public int? months { get; set; }
        public int rankValue { get; set;}
        public int rankDelta { get;set;}
        public int reachrankValue { get; set; }
        public int reachRankDelta { get; set; }
        public decimal reachPerMillionValue { get; set; }
        public decimal reachPerMillionDeltaPercentage { get; set; }

        public decimal pageViewsPerMillionValue { get; set; }
        public decimal pageViewsPerMillionDeltaPercentage { get; set; }
        public decimal pageViewsRankValue { get; set; }
        public decimal pageViewsRankDelta { get; set; }
        public decimal pageViewsPerUserValue { get; set; }
        public decimal pageViewsPerUserDeltaPercentage { get; set; }

    }
    public class ContributingSubdomain
    {
        public string dataUrl { get; set; }
        public int? months { get; set; }
        public int? days { get; set; }
        public decimal reachPercentage { get; set; }
        public decimal pageViewsPercentage { get; set; }
        public decimal pageViewsPerUser { get; set; }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use XPath instead of referencing nodes by index.

E.g. XPath to get the URL (untested code):

```
var url = node.SelectSingleNode("//aws2:ContactInfo/aws2:DataUrl/text());
```

instead of:

```
if(node.ChildNodes[i].Name== "aws:ContactInfo")
{
    merchwebsite.WebsiteName=node.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
}
```